# a couple of doubts about String in Java

Tags: java, string

1. what is the difference between: `String a[]` and `List<String> a`?
2. Is `String a[]` correct? or for defining array of strings we should use `String[] a` always?
3. When we declare `String[] a`, do we need to initialize it always?

---

Suppose i do this:

```
String[] a = new String[5];
a[2] = "Hello";
a[3] = "World";
a[2] = "Good Bye";
```

Since array is stored contiguously in memory and when i modify a string new string object is created. How does all these strings stored and modified in Java for all of the above statements?

Comment: this is a very basic java stater question. a google search would have given you the answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `String a[]` is a native Java array of `String`s.  `List a` is a raw (untyped) `List` (see [*The Java Collections*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/)).  You probably want the genericised version: `List<String> a`.  There are far too many differences to list here; you should follow that link!
2. `String a[]` and `String[] a` are equivalent.  `String[] a` is the convention, though.
3. `String[] a` is actually a reference.  If it's a non-local variable, it will be implicitly initialised to `null` if you don't explicitly initialise it.  You commonly will want to do something like `String[] a = new String[10];`.
4. Each element of the array is a reference to a `String`; the underlying data itself is not stored in the array.

Comment: What about rest of the questions? Also, for first question, String array  is stored contiguously in memory while Strings in list may not necessarily stored contiguously. Is this correct?

Comment: @Tarun Kumar: no, that's not correct. What is stored contiguously in a Java String array is *references* the the string object, which themselves can be apread around all over the heap. And the same is true for the most common List implementation ArrayList, which is based on an array, as the name suggests.

Comment: So, you mean even lists in Java store reference to actual String data and these references might not necessarily be contiguous in memory?

Comment: Around implicit initialization - that's fine for instance and static variables, but local variables must be definitely assigned before they can be read.